# How to split row names when some of rows have two dots in R?

Tags: r

The original data frame is like:

```
           2019-10-28   2019-10-29
ABR.PA.Open     5          6
ABR.PA.High     1          8
ABR.PA.Low      3          2
ABR.PA.Close    34         6
ABR.PA.Volume   0          7
ABR.PA.Adjusted 3          4
AT.Open         4          8
AT.High         3          7
AT.Low          2          5
AT.Close        9          4
AT.Volume       7          4
AT.Adjusted     4          3
```

[image]

The shape that I want to have is:

```
Tickers Price_Variables 2019-10-28  201910-29                       
ABR.PA      Open            5           6
ABR.PA      High            1           8
ABR.PA      Low             3           2
ABR.PA      Close           34          6
ABR.PA      Volume          0           7
ABR.PA      Adjusted        3           4
AT          Open            4           8
AT          High            3           7
AT          Low             2           5
AT          Close           9           4
AT          Volume          7           4
AT          Adjusted        4           3
```

As you see first six rows have two dots and the others have one dot each. I was going to use strsplit, but I couldn't because of that. Also I need to have two additional column names, "Tickers" and "Price_Variables". What should I have do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring those rownames as separate column and then use `extract` from `tidyr` to create two new columns.

```
df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column('Tickers') %>%
  tidyr::extract(Tickers, c('Tickers', 'Price_Variables'), regex = '(.*)\\.(.*)')

#   Tickers Price_Variables 2019-10-28 2019-10-29
#1   ABR.PA            Open          5          6
#2   ABR.PA            High          1          8
#3   ABR.PA             Low          3          2
#4   ABR.PA           Close         34          6
#5   ABR.PA          Volume          0          7
#6   ABR.PA        Adjusted          3          4
#7       AT            Open          4          8
#8       AT            High          3          7
#9       AT             Low          2          5
#10      AT           Close          9          4
#11      AT          Volume          7          4
#12      AT        Adjusted          4          3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(`2019-10-28` = c(5L, 1L, 3L, 34L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 4L), `2019-10-29` = c(6L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 
8L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("ABR.PA.Open", 
"ABR.PA.High", "ABR.PA.Low", "ABR.PA.Close", "ABR.PA.Volume", 
"ABR.PA.Adjusted", "AT.Open", "AT.High", "AT.Low", "AT.Close", 
"AT.Volume", "AT.Adjusted"))
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, I got an error, "Error in tibble::rownames_to_column(., "Tickers") : 
  is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE" I posted a picture of my original df. I think this error is caused by the first column of the original df. Right?

Comment: I think that is because you don't have a dataframe. Maybe it's a `zoo` object in which case we need to first convert it into dataframe. Can you post `dput(head(df))` ?

Comment: "structure(c(26.16, 26.1665, 25.940001, 26.15, 1910, 24.099134,......." I see that it says that "Large matrix (239778 elements, 2 MB) in the environment window. Isn't it a data frame?

Comment: What does `class(df)` return?

Comment: [1] "matrix" "array"

Comment: Can you convert it to dataframe and then try `df %>% as.data.frame %>% tibble::rownames_to_column('Tickers').....`

Comment: I've look up how to convert matrix into data frame. I used melt function of reshape2 package, and it just changes whole data shape, showing only three columns (Date, rownames, values). Do you know any simpler way?

Comment: It is not possible to help looking at an image. Can you post few rows of your data using `dput` ?

Comment: structure(c(25.190001, 25.351999, 24.629999, 25.134501, 21237, 
25.134501, 24.85, 24.950001, 24.76, 24.950001, 1863, 24.950001, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(12L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("ABR.PA.Open", "ABR.PA.High", "ABR.PA.Low", 
"ABR.PA.Close", "ABR.PA.Volume", "ABR.PA.Adjusted", "ABR.PB.Open", 
"ABR.PB.High", "ABR.PB.Low", "ABR.PB.Close", "ABR.PB.Volume", 
"ABR.PB.Adjusted"), c("2020-09-24", "2020-09-25")))

Comment: This is a short version of my original matrix

Comment: `as.data.frame()` works for me for the data you shared. Try updated answer.